# How can I create margins in included pdf to print it properly

Tags: margins, pdfpages, printing

I have created a pdf file with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[scale=1.31, nup=2x1,pages=2-5,trim=1.5cm 1.5cm 1.5cm 1.5cm]{sh1.pdf}


\end{document}
```

And then I created a `ps` file like this:

```
pdf2ps mergeS.pdf mergeS2.ps
gs -sDEVICE=ps2write -o A7.ps  -r120x120 mergeS2.ps
```

**NOW** I have the problem that the pages are not moved to the right from the left margin far enough and the same from the top margin towards the bottom.

Which command can I use to fix this ? Can I even *center* the 2 columns to the A4 paper format so that it has the same margins on all 4 sides and then 1 margin slightly enlarge ?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Great. Could you kindly add for me a MWE ? How can I *center* the included `pdf` for all 4 margins ?

Comment: Actually, to do all 4 margins you might need to change the aspect ratio for the source pages.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I can do **nothing** with the margins. Every attempt to change my left margin has failed (and it has remained the same and negative regardless of the parameters chosen). Could you kindly give here a source code which would work ? Also, please note that I have `nup=2x1`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo And finally I want to print it on *both* sides of `A4` .

Comment: Printing on both sides is an option for the printer driver (OS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This puts a 1cm margin on all 4 sides.  Slight fudge factors were needed to get a perfect fit.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}% MWE only

\pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{(\paperheight-2cm)/(\paperwidth-3cm)}% 1cm margin
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\delta}{\paperwidth-2cm-2*\scale*(\paperheight-3cm)-4mm}% 4mm fudge factor

\begin{document}
\includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-4,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% 3mm too high
  trim=1.5cm 1.5cm 1.5cm 1.5cm]{test5.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]