# Right placement in `.pdf` file but wrong after `pdf2ps mergeS.pdf mergeS2.ps`

Tags: pdf, rotating, pdfpages, printing, ghostscript

I've asked a related question [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672821/how-can-i-create-margins-in-included-pdf-to-print-it-properly):

I have now good placed pdf together with the right rotation:
[image]

**However, after**

```
pdf2ps mergeS.pdf mergeS2.ps
gs -sDEVICE=ps2write -o A22.ps  -r120x120 mergeS2.ps
```

I'm getting a wrong rotation in my `ps` file and also in my printer:

[image]

This hasn't helped:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
```

Likewise, setting rotated page in `GhostScript` hasn't helped.
How can I rotate for printing and viewing in GS the right rotation ?

Comment: try the ghostscript option `-dAutoRotagePages=/None`  (but why can't you print directly the pdf?)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I really need a `ps` file. Where should I place `-dAutoRotagePages=/None` ? `pdf2ps` doesn't accept it and after `gs` like this `gs -dAutoRotagePages=/None` is already late (everything is already rotated) :-(

Comment: hm, Rotage sounds wrong, try -dAutoRotatePages, and for the value you perhaps need #None or something else depending on your OS (I always forget that). (on windows `ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None test-utf8.ps` works.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Correct. I have created `merge.pdf` correctly rotated from **badly rotated** `merge.ps`. But I need to have correctly rotated `merge.ps` not `merge.pdf`. Also, I got correctly rotated `merge.pdf` immediately from my `Winedit`.

Comment: What do you mean by "also in my printer"? Nevertheless, if the `mergeS.pdf` file generated by LaTeX looks correct, TeX.SX probably is the wrong place to ask. For debugging purposes, you might want to look into the PostScript file itself (which should be plain text) - https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rjl/landscape/ might give some initial hints.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh I mean by `also in my printer` that the cut r.h.s. is also cut after printing the page and in particular is also badly rotated. I need that it would be rotated as in the first picture. In  `the postscript file itself` I cannot find the line which would say `%%Orientation:` at all. So please, how can I change my `.ps` file so that it would look like my first picture in the question ? **Better said, how can I create well rotated page in the resulting `ps`** file with this command: `pdf2ps merS.pdf mergeS2.ps`; `pdf2ps mergeS.pdf -dAutoRotagePages=/None mergeS2.ps` doesn't work at all.

Comment: Probably `pdf2ps -dAutoRotagePages=/None mergeS.pdf mergeS2.ps` and/or `gs -dAutoRotagePages=/None -sDEVICE=ps2write -o A22.ps  -r120x120 mergeS2.ps` does the trick. Probably the rendering-parameter `-dORIENT1=false` of gs helps.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Now it works the very same command (as given in my OQ) which previously didn't. I'm confused what might have happened in my system Windows/AR/GS/ps2pdf/xetex.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Hi, if you wish post an asnwer to my last comment and I'll give you those 100 points so that they won't just expire.